# Sandbox account verification

Tags: wordpress, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using paypal with woocommerce on a wordpress site.

I've set up a developer's account, and made a sandbox account. The profile says the status is unverified, even though I have recived the verification email and followed the link to verify the account. Could it still say unverified because I haven't linked a card to it?

When I try to test paypal checkout on my site I get this error:
Payment error:
    An error (10002) occurred while processing your PayPal payment. Please contact the store owner for assistance.

Comment: Did you turn your payment gateway to sandbox ?

Comment: I ended up using a different account to test it, thanks though

Answer (score 0):

**Error Code Interpretation:**

Authentication/Authorization Failed Username/Password is incorrect.Please check below link for more information

**Reference:**

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/